# Creating and printing Split Normals in Python

Tags: python, normals

I created custom split normals, they show up in the viewport, but how can I get a list of them in python?

```
import bpy

mesh = bpy.context.object.data

mesh.use_auto_smooth = True
mesh.normals_split_custom_set( [(1, 1, 0) for v in mesh.loops] )

for l in mesh.loops:
    print(l.normal)
```

The code above just prints out (0.0,0.0,0.0) vectors, so split normals are probably stored somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

- You need to call `mesh.calc_normals_split()` once before you can access the loop.normals. Otherwise they will all be zero, as you found out.
- In addition to use_auto_smooth needing to be on, polys need to be smooth-shaded (`poly.use_smooth = True`) to use the custom normals.
- Make sure the vectors you pass to split_custom_set are really normalized or you will get [weird results](https://developer.blender.org/T98910).

Comment: mesh.calc_normals_split() did give me results, but they're random(probably auto-calculated by blender, as the function name implies). I want my custom normals to be printed (the (1,1,0) ones).

Comment: You can't ever get [1,1,0], it isn't unit length. Like I said, it has to be normalized.

Comment: Oh, true, I'm dumb. The vector length has to be 1, not individual components. Sorry!